# Filter Directory Listing By Date Listed In Name

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

So I have a massive list of files that I am querying to generate a list of files to be manipulated later. Each file has a date in the name and I need to filter any files that are not within the specific date range.

Files are named as such

```
jflksafjlkasfs_2016-01-01_jkfdfjlkajklldsa.log
j221373213478_2016-01-02_jkdjdsalkdfusalkfl.log
```

In the script I have 2 variable

```
StartDate = 
EndDate =
```

I am currently querying the files using a basic GCI.

```
$htLogFiles.All += Get-Childitem -Path $Directory -OutBuffer 1000 -filter "*.log.gz" |Select FullName, Name
```

I need to filter the list of files to exclude any files that do not fall within the date range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using regex and some dummy files names.  In your example you would want to replace `$fileNames` with your initial `Get-ChildItem` command.  I am just piping the file names to where clause that uses a regex to capture the year, month, and day.  I then pipe that to another where clause that uses the captured numbers to construct a `System.DateTime` object and compares that to the start and end times.

```
$startDate = New-Object -TypeName System.DateTime -ArgumentList @(2016, 1, 2)
$endDate = New-Object -TypeName System.DateTime -ArgumentList @(2016, 1, 4)

$fileNames = @(
"jflksafjlkasfs_2016-01-01_jkfdfjlkajklldsa.log",
"j221373213478_2016-01-02_jkdjdsalkdfusalkfl.log",
"j221373213478_2016-01-03_jkdjdsalkdfusalkfl.log",
"j221373213478_2016-01-04_jkdjdsalkdfusalkfl.log",
"j221373213478_2016-01-05_jkdjdsalkdfusalkfl.log")

$fileNames | 
? { $_ -match "_(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)_" } |
? { 
    $date = New-Object System.DateTime -ArgumentList $Matches[1], $Matches[2], $Matches[3] 
    $date -ge $startDate -and $date -le $endDate
}
```

Here is the output from the above command:

> j221373213478_2016-01-02_jkdjdsalkdfusalkfl.log 
>   j221373213478_2016-01-03_jkdjdsalkdfusalkfl.log 
>   j221373213478_2016-01-04_jkdjdsalkdfusalkfl.log

I think the modified version to fit your scenario would look something like this (there may be some minor syntax errors):

```
Get-Childitem -Path $Directory -OutBuffer 1000 -filter "*.log" | 
? { $_.Name -match "_(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)_" } |
? { 
    $date = New-Object System.DateTime -ArgumentList $Matches[1], $Matches[2], $Matches[3] 
    $date -ge $startDate -and $date -le $endDate
} |
Select FullName, Name
```

Comment: haha it works perfect! But how/why? Could you please either explain how it works and/or point me in the direction so I can learn it myself.

Comment: @user1451070 Which parts are you unclear on?  I will try and explain them better.

Comment: How does it get $Matches[1], 2 etc.

Comment: The `$Matches` variable is created by PowerShell any time the `-match` operator is called and contains the results of the last match operation that was performed.  So when the match is performed in the second line the `$matches` variable is created and it contains each of the capture groups (the stuff between the parans).  So in the third operation in the pipeline I am just grabbing the `$Matches` variable that was created in the second operation in the pipeline.